# prettier-vscode is ignoring my tabs setting

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, indentation, prettier, prettier-vscode

I'm using Visual Studio Code and the prettier plugin for it, version 5.8.0.
In the extension settings of prettier I configured a tab width of 12.
I also configured a tab width of 12 in a .prettierrc.json file:

```
{
    "useTabs": true,
    "tabWidth": 12,
}
```

The editor tab size of Visual Studio Code is set to 4.
When I now create a new file and format it (auto save and auto format on save is enabled and default formatter is set to 'esbenp.prettier-vscode) then it's not indented by 12, but by 4. So my prettier settings are worthless.

Why? What did I wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem as you, and it's driving me insane

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your package.json:

```
"prettier": {
    "tabWidth": 12
}
```

Comment: No, you can't add that to your package.json.